# Fast element wise multiplication of a column vector with a row vector in PLS

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix-multiplication

I'm using Matlab to perform large number of iterations with partial least squares (PLS) as the algorithm for processing data in each iteration. It runs quite slow. Using `profile` to monitor the time used by each line of my codes shows that the line `X = X-t*p'`, where `X` is a matrix of size `r` by `c` and `t` and `p` are column vectors of size `r` and `c`, costs most of the time. I think the reason can be the extending of memory by `t*p'` which generates a matrix from the two vectors, a well known cause that slower the computation in Matlab. Is there a way to speed up this?

The PLS codes are:

```
for iter = 1:maxiter % maxiter is defaultedly set as 10,000
    % preparing data....
    ......
    % perform PLS using NIPALS algorithm
    for a = 1:A
        x = X'*y;
        w = x/norm(x);
        t = X*w;
        tt = sum(t.^2);
        p = X'*(t/tt);
        q = sum(y.*t)/tt;
        X = X-t*p';     % updata X, this line costs most of the time
        y = y-t*q;        % updata y
    end

    % output w, P, q
    .......
end
```

Comment: I think the builtin vector multiplication is already a good implementation that you couldn't easily optimise further. It may be better to look into some other optimisations: Can you adapt your algorithm to avoid the multiplication? Can you use less iterations?

Comment: Why I was downvoted? If I can find the solution, I think I would not post any question here.

Comment: @m7913d I agree with you that Matlab has greatly optimized the matrix multiplication. So I posted the algorithm I implemented. I have spent several days to try to optimize the algorithm and decrease the number of iterations, but I failed.

Comment: If you want to optimise your PLS algorithm in general, it may be a good idea to reflect it in your title. Have you tried [`plsregress`](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/plsregress.html)?

Comment: @m7913d A great reminder. It's much faster than mine. But problems exist in the output results probably due to lack of parameters suitable for my situation in `plsregress`, so I will carefully study the way in which Matlab implements PLS to find out any tips that can speed up my PLS. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid deflation of `X` by `X = X-t*p';`, there are three ways, as discussed in ["Computational performance and cross-validation error precision of five PLS algorithms using designed and real data sets"](http://marcia.iqm.unicamp.br/Pub134.pdf). I used the following algorithm:

- [SIMPLS](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016974399385002X)

  ```
  for iter = 1:maxtest
      % preparing data...
      ... ...
      for a = 1:A
          % for a vector, eigenvector of S'*S is always 1
          ri = s;
          t = X*ri;
          normt = sqrt(sum(t.^2));
          t = t/normt;
          ri = ri/normt;
          % X loadings
          pi = X'*t;
          q = y'*t;
          %u = y*q;
          v = pi;
          if a > 1
              v = v-V(:,1:a-1)*(V(:,1:a-1)'*pi);
              %u = u-T(:,1:a-1)*(T(:,1:a-1)'*u);
          end
          v = v/sqrt(sum(v.^2));
          s = s-v*(v'*s);

          V(:,a) = v;
          R(:,a) = ri;
          Q(a) = q;
      end
      % PLS coefficient...
      b = R*Q;
      ...
  end
  ```
- [NIPALS-y](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/(SICI)1099-128X(199701)11:1%3C73::AID-CEM435%3E3.0.CO;2-%23/abstract)

  ```
  for iter = 1:maxtest
      % preparint data...
      ... ...
      % NIPALS
      for a = 1:A
          x = X'*y;
          rx = x/norm(x);
          w = rx;
          if a > 1
              rx = rx-R(:,1:a-1)*(P(:,1:a-1)'*w);
          end
          t = X*rx;
          tt = sum(t.^2);
          P(:,a) = X'*t/tt;
          q(a) = y'*t/tt;
          y = y-t*q(a);
          % W(:, a) = w;
          R(:, a) = rx;
      end

      % PLS coefficient...
      b = R*q;
      ... ...
  end
  ```
- Bidiagonalization

  ```
  for iter = 1:maxtest
      v = X'*y/norm(X'*y);
      u = X*v;
      normu = sqrt(sum(u.^2));
      u = u/normu;
      R(1) = normu;
      V(:,1) = v;
      U(:,1) = u;
      for a = 2:A
          v = X'*u-normu*v;
          normv = sqrt(sum(v.^2));
          v = v/normv;
          u = X*v-normv*u;
          normu = sqrt(sum(u.^2));
          u = u/normu;
          U(:,a) = u;
          V(:,a) = v;
          R(a-1,a) = normv;
          R(a,a) = normu;
      end
      % PLS coefficients...
      b = V*(R\(U'*y));
  end
  ```

Using test data with size of `43 by 195` and 10 fold cross validation, the bidiagonalization method is the fastest, consistent with the results of the paper.